# regex to find first directory in URL if domain not in net, com or org

Tags: regex, url

I am sttrugling in getting a regex to extract the domain extension of a URL https://sub.hello.nl/nl/shop (in this case "nl") or the first two char subdomain between dots in case the domain extension is "com", "net" or "org" http://sub.ca.hello.com/en/shop ("ca" in this other case)

http://sub.hello.nl/nl/shop -> nl

http://sub.ca.hello.com/en/shop -> ca

I got this little so far:

```
.[a-zA-Z]{2}\/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `(?<=\.)[A-Za-z]{2}(?=\.[^/]*\.(?:com|org)(?:/|$))|(?<=/)[A-Za-z]{2}(?=/)` will do. See https://regex101.com/r/IYDnm2/1 and https://regex101.com/r/IYDnm2/2.

Comment: Perhaps with 2 capturing groups `http://[^\n/]+\.(?:(?!com|net|org)([A-Za-z]+)|([A-Za-z]+)(?:\.[^.\n]*)\.com)/` https://regex101.com/r/OJvtzs/1

Comment: Thank you both! I see it working in the examples you attached but it does not in an oracle regexp_substr expresion. Any specific regex flavor?